# Group lines with same ID

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to perform a grouping by ID of each line, however my understanding of the group_by function must be limited, as it seems not to work as I expect it to.

Here is a MWE, for the data (saved as levantamento.csv):

```
pid,all_t1,all_t2,eat_t1,eat_t2,dm_t2,hd_t2,mig_t2,epi_t2,adhd_t1,adhd_t2
146966400,579,792,1583,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
253440300,1492,2588,NA,5145,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
250135300,2830,122,NA,NA,3957,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
253440300,1492,2588,NA,NA,NA,5145,NA,NA,NA,NA
253440300,1492,2588,NA,NA,NA,NA,4049,NA,NA,NA
253440300,1492,2588,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,5145,NA,NA
261505300,3226,3957,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2861,NA,NA
138156300,1706,1096,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,731,NA
252145300,4414,4414,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3319,NA
254666300,3042,3042,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3042,NA
257100400,365,365,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,365,NA
261505300,3226,3957,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2861,NA
252145300,4414,4414,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3319
254666300,3042,3042,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3042
257100400,365,365,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,365
261505300,3226,3957,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2861
```

I want the repeated values to be aggregated and keep the adhd_t1 and adhd_t2 per line:

```
         pid all_t1 all_t2 eat_t1 eat_t2 dm_t2 hd_t2 mig_t2 epi_t2 adhd_t1 adhd_t2
 9 252145300   4414   4414     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    3319      3319
10 254666300   3042   3042     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    3042      3042
11 257100400    365    365     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     365      365
12 261505300   3226   3957     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    2861      2861
```

But when I run:

`read_csv("levantamento.csv") %>% group_by(pid, adhd_t1, adhd_t2)`

I get:

```
         pid all_t1 all_t2 eat_t1 eat_t2 dm_t2 hd_t2 mig_t2 epi_t2 adhd_t1 adhd_t2
       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 146966400    579    792   1583     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA      NA      NA
 2 253440300   1492   2588     NA   5145    NA    NA     NA     NA      NA      NA
 3 250135300   2830    122     NA     NA  3957    NA     NA     NA      NA      NA
 4 253440300   1492   2588     NA     NA    NA  5145     NA     NA      NA      NA
 5 253440300   1492   2588     NA     NA    NA    NA   4049     NA      NA      NA
 6 253440300   1492   2588     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA   5145      NA      NA
 7 261505300   3226   3957     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA   2861      NA      NA
 8 138156300   1706   1096     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     731      NA
 9 252145300   4414   4414     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    3319      NA
10 254666300   3042   3042     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    3042      NA
11 257100400    365    365     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     365      NA
12 261505300   3226   3957     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    2861      NA
13 252145300   4414   4414     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA      NA    3319
14 254666300   3042   3042     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA      NA    3042
15 257100400    365    365     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA      NA     365
16 261505300   3226   3957     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA      NA    2861
```

- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are aggregating i.e. sum, use `df1 %>% group_by(pid, all_t1, all_t2) %>% summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: I noticed while pasting the last numeral was removed, will correct. Look last eight lines and two last variables (adhd_t1, _t2)

Comment: Your expected output only shows 4 pid, whereas there are 8 pid in the input showed

Comment: Exactly, last four are unique, the four before that are repeated pids... I was expecting to convert the eight lines into four keeping adhd_t1 and adhd_t2 four these.

Comment: The logic is not clear.  If you want to remove those non-duplicated groups, `df1 %>% group_by(pid, all_t1, all_t2) %>% filter(n() > 1) %>% summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')`